# How to transfer a binary variable into a continuous variable in OPL Script?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, opl

I have a binary decision variable X and I need to convert it into a continuous variable so it can take continuous values between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0.3). I need to learn how to change a decision variable type in the OPL script part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoorelaxinteger.mod)

> //Now let's see how easy it is to relax integrity constraints and
> //turn a MIP into LP, solve and get dual value (shadow price)

> ```
> int nbKids=300;
> float costBus40=500;
> float costBus30=400;
>  
> dvar int+ nbBus40;
> dvar int+ nbBus30;
>  
> minimize
>  costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
>  
> subject to
> {
>  ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
> }
> main {
>   var status = 0;
>   thisOplModel.generate();
>   if (cplex.solve()) {
>     writeln("Integer Model");   
>     writeln("OBJECTIVE: ",cplex.getObjValue());   
>     
>   }
>   // relax integrity constraint
>   thisOplModel.convertAllIntVars();
>  
>   if (cplex.solve()) {
>     writeln("Relaxed Model");   
>     writeln("OBJECTIVE: ",cplex.getObjValue());  
>     
>     writeln("dual of the kids constraint = ",thisOplModel.ctKids.dual);
>   }
>    
>  
> }
> ```

Comment: I have multiple decision variables some of them are boolean and other ones are integer and I need to relax only one specific boolean decision variable not all of them. It should take a float value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Then see https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MID=89265&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7

Comment: This method worked but in my heuristic algorithm, I need to convert back some of my relaxed variables back to boolean. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Then see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoorelaxoneintegervariable.mod